# How do I remove this space?

Tags: html, css

Thanks in advance ! I tried float, margin, and padding nothing without any help, I wanted to be just sticked to the top corner of the background ... screen shot of the problem

http://www.mediafire.com/?6ngtuh4k5nf43r2

Comment: How do I remove this time?
Please be more specific with describing the problem. Please also post the code you are having trouble with, rather than just a link.

Comment: How people can help you when you just said nothing is working, without any code?

Comment: Code is at the link...

Comment: -1 for supporting the Quran ! Religion is nothing that should be supported by intelligent people. And yes, i'm totally serious with that.

Answer (score 2):

That space is (probably) the body's, not the element's.

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Hard to tell because I can't see the code inside your `<body>` tag in the screenshot, but almost certainly that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your css:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also consider to use [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) it helps with browser inconsistences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS reset tool to reset all the browser-default styles, for example add following rules at the top of your default css file.

```
html{color:#000;background:#FFF}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td,select{margin:0;padding:0}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}fieldset,img{border:0}/*address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal}*/ol,ul{list-style:none}caption,th{text-align:left}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal}q:before,q:after{content:''}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal}sup{vertical-align:text-top}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%}legend{color:#000}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I start a new project i always have this in my css file

```
*{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;

   /* Optional Below */ 
   box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This resets the padding and margin on everything ( not:box-sizing ).